# Multiple contexts in JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

How can I access two seperate vocabs in JSON-LD, can I use 2 @contexts?
e.g.

```
{
"@context": {
  "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
  "first_name": "givenName",
  "last_name": "familyName
  }
"@context": {
  "@vocab": "http://our_own_schema.org/",
  "Time": "inputTime"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide multiple `@context`. If they contain duplicated terms, the most recently defined term gets used. [See examples 27 and 28](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#advanced-context-usage). But if you want to mix vocabularies within the same object, this doesn’t work.

To allow mixing vocabularies within the same object, you could define all vocabularies in the `@context` at the top of the document. Each vocabulary can have a prefix, which allows you to use [compact IRIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#compact-iris). One vocabulary can be [the default one (without prefix)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#default-vocabulary).

- With default vocabulary:

  ```json
  "@context": 
  [
    "http://schema.org/",
    {"oos": "http://our_own_schema.org/"}
  ],
  ```

  The key `name` expands to `http://schema.org/name`,
  the key `oos:name` expands to `http://our_own_schema.org/name`.
- Without default vocabulary:

  ```json
  "@context": 
  {
    "schema": "http://schema.org/",
    "oos": "http://our_own_schema.org/"
  },
  ```

  The key `name` would be ignored,
  the key `schema:name` expands to `http://schema.org/name`,
  the key `oos:name` expands to `http://our_own_schema.org/name`.

Note: It’s always possible to use [absolute IRIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#iris) as keys. You don’t have to define these in a context.

Comment: @BigBlueHat: Thanks for your edit :) Did you remove `@vocab` because it’s shorter, or is there something else to it?

Comment: happy to help. :) Using `@vocab` states a simple prefix for all related identifiers whereas using an IRI as a direct value of `@context` states the use of a context file--which can define thing well beyond simple prefixing. Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you use compact IRIs in context?`"@context": 
{
  "schema": "http://schema.org/",
  "note": "schema:description"
},`

Comment: @Miranda: Yes, should be fine.